# how to check if ssh works without connecting to server

Tags: ssh

I just want to check whether following code will work or not. It is like a validation

```
su -oracle "ssh  oracle@$MY_IP -o 'BatchMode=yes' -o 'ConnectionAttempts=1'"
returnCode=$?

echo "$returnCode"
 if [ $returnCode != 0 ]
 then
  echo "Configuration is not valid"
  return 1;
 else
  echo "Configuration is  valid"
  return 0;
 fi
```

When I run my script, it just gives me empty prompt. I can not enter to if statement. it seems script is trying to connect MY_IP.

How can I validate my statement without changing user and connecting to IP.

Comment: So you are trying to ensure you can still login without logging in?

Comment: I am not sure if it is really possible but yeah.

Comment: What are the most probably events you are guarding against?  Examples: Network failures, pam failures, sshd failures?

Comment: I am just trying to make a health check procedure, it will run everyday and report if ssh is not working...

Comment: It works for me in Linux (are you using Solaris?). For my test I did: export MY_IP="192.168.246.1" ; su mvaldez -c "ssh mvaldez@$MY_IP -o 'BatchMode=yes' -o 'ConnectionAttempts=1'" ; echo $?

Comment: if you are trying to see if the daemon is listening for connections, you could use `netcat`. or are you trying to see if a user can successfully login?

Comment: @MV. yes I am using Solaris. Since ssh keys are generated for MY_IP server, when I executed related script it just connect to MY_IP prompt.

Comment: @llua Weill I don't want user to login MY_IP server. I just want to see that if needed it can login the server... I am not sure if I could explain myself clearly... Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only test to ensure that you can reach the other machine and log in there is to log in. Run a command that does nothing.

```
su -c "ssh  oracle@$MY_IP -o 'BatchMode=yes' -o 'ConnectionAttempts=1' true" oracle
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the need to `su` here... your `ssh` command is already using the oracle user

Comment: @MikePennington I left that in place. Presumably only the local `oracle` user has a private key that's authorized to log in as the remote `oracle` user, or there's some other authentication mechanism that requires `oracle` to run ssh.